# file upload in angularjs 2, got an error

Tags: file-upload, angular

i got an error "angular2-polyfills.js:126 GET http://localhost:3000/ng2-uploader/ng2-uploader 404 (Not Found)" in image upload in angularjs 2. but the class is in there in my folder structure. how i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your SystemJS configuration isn't correct. You could try the following:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    map: {
      'ng2-uploader': 'node_modules/ng2-uploader'
    },
    packages: {
      (...)   
      'ng2-uploader': {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
  (...)
</script>
```